# blogdown::serve() rebuild .rmd files multiple time

Tags: r, blogdown

When I run > blogdown::serve_site() 3 times, I get:

```
Rendering content/contribute.rmd
Rendering content/promotion.rmd
Rendering content/contribute.rmd
Rendering content/promotion.rmd
Rendering content/contribute.rmd
Rendering content/promotion.rmd
```

If I do it 4 times, Rstudio freeze!

using blogdown::stop_server() reinitialise and I get only each rendering once. This extra rendering happens only for .rmd files in the content folder, not the blog posts one.

The whole website can be forked from https://github.com/open-science-promoters/RDM-promotion. Did anyone get that problem already? I am using

```
‘blogdown’ version 0.6

#> R version 3.5.0 (2018-04-23)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.4
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] compiler_3.5.0  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2
#>  [5] tools_3.5.0     htmltools_0.3.6 yaml_2.1.19     Rcpp_0.12.17   
#>  [9] stringi_1.2.3   rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1  
#> [13] digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.10.1
```

Answer (score 0):

ok got the problem: the .rmd files were lacking the yaml for new content and hugo add problem dealing with it. Adding

```
---
categories: []
tags: []
---
```

on top of the .rmd file was enough to deal with the problem (and put that .rmd content under the normal template for single pages!)